# Data transfer between two android phones

Tags: android, communication, data-transfer, communication-protocol

I want to transmit data (few bytes) between 2 Andriod  phones over as long a distance as possible. I don't want to use WiFi. Communication has to be directly between the 2 devices. Would it be possible to send and receive data over FM if I attach an FM transmitter? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Not. I think its not possible. Android receives only allowed frequency approx. 88MHZ to 108MHz which is not allowed legally for hobbyists. If you'll communicate beyond this frequency that will not be received by android and if you'll communicate within legal band, it will be overlapped and not legal. You should prefer online data communication rather.

Comment: What if I transmit on 867 MHz which is license free and then use a receiver at the other end as well?

Comment: yes surely, you can if you are able to successfully operate and attach external FM transmitter. But this will work for limited range. Your frequency may be overlapped with others for much longer distances. @pranavgore